# Similar to GSON in Jackson for arrays

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I am trying to convert an array or List (java) to JSON format. I have seen that in GSON we can do a the following:

```
data.add("hello");
data.add(someobject);
String gson = new Gson().toJson(data);
```

Is there any similar way in Jackson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an equivalent in Jackson: [`ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
List data = new ArrayList();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

data.add("hello");
data.add(someobject);

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
```

Comment: thanks, it is giving the following output. How to parse in JS?[{"topicBody":"Test10","videoAudioUrl":null,"topicGuid":10,"userGuid":0},{"topicBody":"Test22","videoAudioUrl":null,"topicGuid":2,"userGuid":0},{"topicBody":"Test4","videoAudioUrl":null,"topicGuid":4,"userGuid":0},{"topicBody":"Test11","videoAudioUrl":null,"topicGuid":11,"userGuid":0}]

Comment: use `JSON.parse(jsonString)`, e.g.: `var array = JSON.parse('[{"topicBody":"Test10","videoAudioUrl":null,"topicGuid":10,"userGuid":0},{"to‌​picBody":"Test22", ... etc. ... }]'); var obj = array[0]`